# Is this proof of complimentary space correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to prove that the vector space of all odd and even functions are complimentary in the space of all real fucntions *V*. So I have to show that an element e from even functions plus an element o from odd functions equals to some function in the whole space *V*. I assumed this function from *V* to be the constant zero function. The sum of an even function f(x) = f(-x) and an odd function f (-x) = - f (-x) is

*f(-x) - f(-x) = 0*

which is the constant zero functions from V.

Does this proof make any sense, or is it totally wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Compl**i**mentary means politely flattering, whereas compl**e**mentary means completing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be a real function. Let $$g(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2$$ and $$h(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2$$Note that $f=g+h$, $g$ is even, and $h$ is odd.

Comment: But I don't see how g is even and h is odd. I mean f(x) can be any functions, cannot it?

Comment: @Uzi Plug in $-x$ into $g,h$. See what you get.

Comment: Oh now it all clicked! And is saying that only the zero function is both odd and even enough  of a proof that g intersection h is zero?

Comment: @Uzi That's right.